# Error using boost::signals2::signal as handler

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

In the following code:

```
   boost::signals2::signal<void(const boost::system::error_code&)> signal;
   socket.async_connect(endpoint, boost::ref(signal));
```

(Found at http://liveworkspace.org/code/e04910cbcc4cfd9e42e34d1af55c393e)

I get this error:

> In file included from boost/asio/detail/wrapped_handler.hpp:18:0,
>   from boost/asio/io_service.hpp:24,
>   from boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:20,
>   from boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:19,
>   from boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
>   from boost/asio.hpp:20,
>   from source.cpp:2:
>   boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp: In member function 'void boost::asio::detail::binder1<
>       boost::reference_wrapper >,
>       boost::system::error_code
>   ::operator()()':
>   boost/asio/handler_invoke_hook.hpp:64:3:   instantiated from 'void boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke(
>       boost::asio::detail::binder1<
>         boost::reference_wrapper >,
>         boost::system::error_code
>   , ...
>     )'
>   boost/asio/detail/handler_invoke_helpers.hpp:39:3:   instantiated from 'void
>     boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke(
>       const boost::asio::detail::binder1<
>         boost::reference_wrapper >,
>         boost::system::error_code
>   &, boost::reference_wrapper > &
>     )'
>   boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:73:3:   instantiated from 'void boost::asio::detail
>     ::asio_handler_invoke(
>       const boost::asio::detail::binder1<
>         boost::reference_wrapper >,
>         boost::system::error_code
>   &,
>       boost::asio::detail::binder1<
>         boost::reference_wrapper >,
>         boost::system::error_code
>   *
>     )'
>   boost/asio/detail/handler_invoke_helpers.hpp:39:3:   instantiated from 'void
>     boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke(
>       const boost::asio::detail::binder1<
>         boost::reference_wrapper >,
>         boost::system::error_code
>   &,
>       boost::asio::detail::binder1<
>         boost::reference_wrapper >,
>         boost::system::error_code
>   &
>     )'
>   boost/asio/detail/completion_handler.hpp:63:7:   instantiated from 'static void boost::asio::detail
>     ::completion_handler<
>       boost::asio::detail::binder1<
>         boost::reference_wrapper >,
>         boost::system::error_code
>
> ::do_complete(
>       boost::asio::detail::boost::asio::detail::task_io_service *,
>       boost::asio::detail::boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation *, boost::system::error_code, unsigned int
>     )'
>   boost/asio/detail/completion_handler.hpp:38:17:   instantiated from 'boost::asio::detail
>     ::completion_handler<
>       boost::asio::detail::binder1<
>         boost::reference_wrapper >,
>         boost::system::error_code
>
> ::completion_handler(
>       boost::asio::detail::binder1<
>         boost::reference_wrapper >,
>         boost::system::error_code
>
> )'
>   boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.hpp:50:3:   instantiated from 'void boost::asio::detail
>     ::task_io_service::post(
>       boost::asio::detail::binder1<
>         boost::reference_wrapper >,
>         boost::system::error_code
>
> )'
>   boost/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:80:3:   instantiated from 'void boost::asio::io_service::post(Handler)'
>   boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:649:9:   instantiated from 'void boost::asio::basic_socket<
>       boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service 
>   ::async_connect(
>       boost::asio::basic_socket >::boost
>       ::asio::ip::basic_endpoint &,
>       boost::reference_wrapper>
>     )'
>   source.cpp:10:53:   instantiated from here
>   boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:40:5: error: no match for call to '(
>       boost::reference_wrapper>
>     ) (const boost::system::error_code &)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your signature is wrong? You need to specify a placeholder for the error_code

Try

```
boost::signals2::signal<void(const boost::system::error_code&)> signal;
socket.async_connect(endpoint, boost::bind(boost::ref(signal), _1));
```

Comment: why this is correct for boost::function ?

   boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&)> signal;
   socket.async_connect(endpoint, signal);

Answer (score 1):

Ralf's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148358/error-on-using-boostsignals2signal-as-handler/5155548#5155548) is close, I think you need to bind the placeholder to the `signal` functor:

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;

int 
main() 
{
   io_service ios;
   ip::tcp::socket socket(ios);
   const ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(
           ip::address::from_string(""), 
           0
           );

   boost::signals2::signal<void(const boost::system::error_code&)> signal;
   socket.async_connect(
           endpoint, 
           boost::bind(
               boost::ref(signal), _1
               ) 
       );
}
```

example:

```
samm@macmini ~$ g++ -I /opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/local/lib -lboost_system signal.cc 
samm@macmini ~$ echo $?
0
samm@macmini ~$
```